# Participle Attachment

Tags: dangling-participles

In the following sentence what word does the participle phrase "leaving it damp, wrinkled and only a little less discolored." attach to. Is its use correct? Is there a special category of participles that "leaving," which carries with it a sense of completion, is a member of?

Taking his shirt out of the plastic bag, he shook the garment a couple of times, ran water over the bloodied neck and dried it under the hand drier, leaving it damp, wrinkled and only a little less discolored.

Comment: The default assumption should be that it attaches to the closest credible preceding clause. In this case that's *dried it under the hand drier*, which makes perfect sense to me. Obviously it makes no sense to attach it to *ran water over the bloodied neck*, and it's really too far away from *he shook the garment...* to make that credible on syntactic grounds (though *semantically* it's at least plausible).

Comment: Right as rain.  I really wish that 1aiway.com still offered their free online tool to create Reed-Kellogg diagrams, which would make answering this kind of question a snap.

Comment: Zan700 No, along with many other participial clauses like this, it's called a **supplementary adjunct** (the kind that don't modify anything). Supplementary because it's not tightly integrated into clause structure, but set off from the rest of the clause by a comma (and a slight pause in speech). It provides useful but non-essential information about the situation. Btw, the opening _taking_ clause is also a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ But wouldn't "Taking his shirt..." attach itself to he? Also just as a gerund is particular use of a participle, but still a participle, is the supplementary adjunct still a participle phrase (clause)?

Comment: Zan700 Hi, I've posted an answer which I hope will address your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taking his shirt out of the plastic bag], **he shook the garment a couple of times, ran water over the bloodied neck and dried it under the hand drier**, [leaving it damp, wrinkled and only a little less discoloured].

The sequence in bold is a coordination of three main clauses; they form the ‘core’ of the sentence (notice that they’re all finite clauses). By contrast, the bracketed expressions are all subjectless non-finite clauses. They don’t attach to anything in the sense that they are modifiers, though "he" is the understood subject (it was "he" who took his shirt out … and "he" who left it damp …. ).

The bracketed adjuncts are gerund-participial clauses headed by “taking” and “leaving”; they are supplements because they don’t modify anything; rather they are loosely attached expressions, set apart from the rest of the sentence by commas, and by a slight pause in speech. They provide useful information of course, but they are non-essential and can be discarded without disturbing the integrity or meaning of the core sentence.

Comment: In the US, the bold text would be considered one complete clause with multiple predicates. "Taking his shirt out of the plastic bag" would be considered a phrase because there is no subject. In conventional diagramming wouldn't "Taking..." be attached to the subject of the main clause? "Loosely attached expressions" make me nervous. I thought participles and participle phrases always functioned as adjectives (unless gerunds) and so modified nouns or pronouns. From the Purdue Owl: Removing his coat, Jack rushed to the river.
The participial phrase functions as an adjective modifying Jack.

Comment: @Zan700 Yes, the part in bold can be considered a coordination of three VPs, each with the subject “he”. Some grammars would consider them to be three separate main clauses with the subject ellipted in the second two. I actually prefer the VP analysis myself. Most non-finite clauses are subjectless (no overt subject), and these are too. The two gerund-participials do have subjects (retrievable from the main clause), so there exists a subject-predicate structure, hence they’re considered clauses.

Comment: Some participial clauses do function as modifiers, cf. “People earning $50,000 a year don’t qualify", but the clause is tightly integrated and inseparable from the noun (people) that it modifies. Additionally, clauses like that do assign a property to the subject, i.e. that of being an earner of $50,000, but “taking his shirt etc and “leaving it damp” do not describe “he” in any way at all; they simply describe what “he” was doing. In your example, the clauses are not integrated into the structure of the sentence, they are parenthetical-like, and hence called supplements.

Comment: We call the supplements clauses because they have a subject-predicate structure, though the subject (“he”) is of course covert. In your Jack example, “removing his coat” is hardly adjectival is it? It does not ascribe a property to Jack, but merely tells us what he was doing. Again, it would be called a supplementary adjunct. Here's a link to the grammar website of the University of London. It gives some useful examples of non-finite clauses (the ones you call phrases) [link](http://www.englicious.org/lesson/clauses/clauses-finite-and-nonfinite-clauses)